# Displaying users who click the button

Tags: views, users

I have 2 user roles in my Drupal 7 site `'A'` and `'B'` respectively:

- users of role `'A'` can create and publish content.
- users of role `'A'` can see content they created on their profile page. (For this purpose I created a block to display content and put it on user's page.)
- users of role `'B'` can **not** create content but they can view all published content.

Content in my case is an invitation to some event (ie "Who wants to play football on Friday?")

Each content has `'Participate'` button which users of role `'B'` can submit.

1. How can I display in `'A'` users pages the names of `'B'` users who want to participate in their event?
2. How can an `'A'` user confirm participation of some `'B'` users and dismiss the rest?

Answer (score -1):

This is quite a complex task your planning – and it's hard to answer in just a few lines of text. I can basically just recommend you have a closer look at the mighty [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module in combination with the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) and the [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/Entityreference) module.

Here's just a vague suggestion / outline of how this *could* probably be done by combining the above modules:

- Put a flag `'participate'` on content type event users of role `'B'` can use
- Define a new content type `'participation'` with checkbox/flag `'confirmed / dismissed'` and reference the event and the user to it, editable by `'A'` users
- Make a rule that generates a new node of content type `'participation'` and alerts users of role `'A'` of a new request
- Extend your profile pages' view with the referenced items of content type `'participation'`

There is probably different ways to do this – most likely also easier ways than the one described above. And then there is also a more specific module '[Rules link event](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_linkevent)' that might fit your demands.